# Does Ti.admob support showing video ads? If not is there any other module for it?

Tags: module, admob, titanium, appcelerator

I am using the Ti.admob module and it works fine for banner ads. However when i use video ads it does not work. Is there a way to make it work? Or any other module i can use in its place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this module to display reward Video with Admob on Titanium : https://github.com/1dir1/admobrewarded

You can check a sample code here : https://github.com/1dir1/admobrewarded/blob/master/ios/example/app.js

Comment: Hi Thomas, The module doesn’t seem to work. Although the manifest is updated to support Ti SDK 7 and above however i couldn’t find a version 0.4 in the release tab. I tried downloading version 0.3 and making the changes to manifest file myself, but it didn’t work. Any suggestion ?